# How to make my JavaScript code more dynamic and scalable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building an app and trying to save data to my database. I have many forms but they are all sending to the same endpoint, my code looks long and boring and I feel that it will be difficult to maintain in the future, so is their a way I can shorten the code like create a function that will automatically submit the form in case I want to add more forms to my app, to make it dynamic and scalable.

here is the code

```
    $('.stepNextBtn1').click(function(){  
    $('#FuielsImg').fadeIn()      
    $.ajax({
        url: '/nexpost',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            '_token': csrf,
            'value': $('.AuthenticationKe').val(),
            'key': 'AuthenticationKey'
        },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function( data ) {
            $('#FuielsImg').fadeOut()      
            if(data.success){
                $('.ShowAutCode').fadeOut()
                $('.AuthenticationKe').val('')
                $('.stepfield1').slideUp('slow')
                $('.stepfield2').slideDown('slow')
            }  else{
                $('.ShowAutCode').fadeIn()
            }      
        } 
    })
})
$('.stepNextBtn2').click(function(){
    $('#FuielsImg').fadeIn()      
    $.ajax({
        url: '/nexpost',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            '_token': csrf,
            'value': $('.COTcode').val(),
            'key': 'COTcode'
        },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function( data1 ) {
            $('#FuielsImg').fadeOut()
            if(data1.success){
                $('.ShowCotCode').fadeOut()
                $('.COTcode').val('')
                $('.stepfield2').slideUp('slow')
                $('.stepfield3').slideDown('slow')
            }  else{
                $('.ShowCotCode').fadeIn()
            }      
        } 
    })
})
$('.stepNextBtn3').click(function(){
    $('#FuielsImg').fadeIn()      
    $.ajax({
        url: '/nexpost',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            '_token': csrf,
            'value': $('.TAXcode').val(),
            'key': 'TAXcode'
        },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function( data2 ) {
            $('#FuielsImg').fadeOut()
            if(data2.success){
                $('.ShowTaxCode').fadeOut()
                $('.TAXcode').val('')
                $('.stepfield3').slideUp('slow')
                $('.stepfield4').slideDown('slow')
            }  else{
                $('.ShowTaxCode').fadeIn()
            }      
        } 
    }) 
})
```

Thanks, its really important to me

Comment: I mean you should move the request portion to a utility file. I would split it up into relevant parts, like showing something when you need to, making requests, handling errors. these should be separate pieces of logic. Your functions can take targets of what to change / affect.

Comment: Can you share HTML also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function to do all the heavy lifting

```
function clickHandler(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5) {
    return function() {
        $('#FuielsImg').fadeIn()
        $.ajax({
            url: '/nexpost',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                '_token': csrf,
                'value': $(p1).val(),
                'key': p2
            },
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#FuielsImg').fadeOut()
                if (data.success) {
                    $(p3).fadeOut()
                    $(p1).val('')
                    $(p4).slideUp('slow')
                    $(p5).slideDown('slow')
                } else {
                    $(p3).fadeIn()
                }
            }
        });
    };
}
$('.stepNextBtn1').click(clickHandler('.AuthenticationKe', 'AuthenticationKey', '.ShowAutCode', '.stepfield1', '.stepfield2'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Jquery, but from your code, since what you are passing into ajax  function is an object, I think you can make a switch statement that set the object appropriately based on the class name of the button clicked

```
switch(event.target.classname) {
   case '.stepNextBtn1':
     obj = {...};
     break;
   case 'stepNextBtn2':
     obj = {...};
     break;
   case 'stepNextBtn3':
     obj = {...};
     break;
   default:
     break
}
```

then you can simplify your code into something like this

```
 $(event.target.classname).click(function(){  
 $('#FuielsImg').fadeIn()
 $.ajax(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some basic software engineering principles might help here!

Keep your code DRY. You are making the same AJAX call three times. Don't Repeat Yourself and make a single function to handle the AJAX calls and then pass in the relevant data to handle the AJAX call and the UI interaction.

```
let ajaxObj = {
    fieldsToClear: ['AuthenticationKe','COTcode','TAXcode'],
    slideUpFields: ['stepfield1','stepfield2','stepfield3']
}

function makeAjaxCall(ajaxData) {
    // Do ajax stuff here

    // then your UI interactions
    ajaxData.fieldsToClear.forEach(elem => {
        $(elem).val('');
    });

    ajaxData.slideUpFields.forEach(elem => {
        $(elem).slideUp('slow');
    })

    return(value);
}
```